# How do grouping for a specific Columns in Pandas + applicate stats on this?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe with different column:

'Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations', 'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', ...

Now first I had to add two columns "Continents" as well "PopEst" (estimated Population).

Now I am asked to create a new dataframe with the Continents as index and columns ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std'].

I know there is for sure a totally simple solution... ;-(

I tried several things after readin a lot online but seem to find a solution:
My idea was to create a new Pandas Dataframe with this

```
Continents=Top15.groupby('Continent')[['PopEst']]
```

Unfortunately this delivers me this when I try to print it:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7faa323ffc50>
```

If I do

```
print(Continents.size())
```

I get this which looked promising

```
Continent
Asia             5
Australia        1
Europe           6
North America    2
South America    1
dtype: int64
```

Unfortunately this looks nice only for .sum and .size. .mean and .std deliver an error as follows:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

And my idea to use this (i.e. to add columns to my newly found dataframe)

```
Continents['size']=Continents.size()
```

give me this error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment
```

I am sure this is done with 2 - 3 lines of code and would ove to know how this works.

Can anyone point me to the correct solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to keep all other columns

```
Top15.assign(sizeofg=Top15.groupby('Continent')['PopEst'].transform('size')).\
        drop_duplicates('Continent')
```

EDIT:
You need [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

```
Top15.groupby('Continent')['PopEst'].agg(['sum','mean','count'])
```

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding. In the end I only need
the Continents as indices
'size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std' with respect to the 'PopEst'

Btw I still try to understand what your code does.

Comment: Thanks. That's it. And with that I found out that my 'PopEst' wasn't float and therefore I had the probs with the .mean()
One more question if it is ok:
In the meantime I tried this:

    popul=Top15[['Continent','PopEst']]

    Continents=popul.agg({'Continent' : ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']})

I tried to pull out the columns I am interested in and tried to apply the agg function to it. But I always get the error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'
Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: @AndreasK. where is your `groupby` when using `agg`? adding groupby `popul.groupby('Something').agg({'Continent' : ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']})`

Comment: Thanks. Yes with groupby it works:
Continents=popul.groupby('Continent').agg(['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std'])

But if I look at the last example of the documentation it should work the other way too: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html#pandas.DataFrame.aggregate

Comment: @AndreasK.`popul.agg(['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std'])` it will work

Comment: Sorry, no. I get this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'

Comment: @AndreasK. BTW , what pandas version you are using ? the method you mention *New in version 0.20.0.*

Comment: 0.18.1 - I found out.